# Operation on each column of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table of the form:

```
d1 <- data.table(read.csv(header=TRUE, file=textConnection("x1,y1,z1
string1,string2,1
string3,string1,2
string3,string5,3")))
```

I am trying to convert this data for usage in Spark. It seems Spark doesn't take string as input or tries to convert it (I am very beginner in Spark):

> File 
>   "/grid/6/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/Z076156/appcache/application_1438295298158_169576/container_1438295298158_169576_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/util.py",
>   line 45, in _parse_libsvm_line
>       label = float(items[0]) ValueError: could not convert string to float:
>   "505",0,"17661674","MULTI-COLORED","0","75",2,131,"2","",0,"XS","5.10

So I am trying to convert all string into numerical factors in R. Here is simple function which I wrote based on my success with conversion of just one column:

```
string2num <- function(d,a){
  l<-unique(c(as.character(d$a)))
  return(as.numeric(factor(d$a, levels=l)))
}
```

However I am not able to apply it over multiple string columns of a tables (due to atomic vector reference in function). Currently writing simple code snippets and debugging but not success. I am expecting some solution in a form:

```
for(i in colnames(d1)){
  if(is.character(d1$i))
    string2num(d1,i)
}
```

or:

```
d1[,lapply(.SD, string2num),.SDcols=is.character(.SD)]
```

or:

```
do.call(rbind(lapply(d1[,sapply(d1,is.character)],string2num)))
```

or may be I don't have any clue of right solution. Expected output will be of form:

```
  x1 y1 z1
1:  1  1  1
2:  2  2  2
3:  2  3  3
```

Notice in x1 column both instances of string3 going for number 1 (one of one mapping (string -> some number) for all string columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
indx <- which(sapply(d1, is.character))
d1[, (indx) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = indx
   ][, (indx) := lapply(.SD, as.integer), .SDcols = indx]
```

or as proposed by @Frank everything in one go:

```
d1[, (indx) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(as.factor(x))), .SDcols=indx]
```

this gives:

```
> d1
   x1 y1 z1
1:  1  2  1
2:  2  1  2
3:  2  3  3
```

---

Used data:

```
d1 <- fread("x1,y1,z1
string1,string2,1
string3,string1,2
string3,string5,3", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: coercing string to number will result in NAs.

Comment: @abhiieor `d1` as created by the code above contains no strings, unless you've put `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` somewhere.

Comment: @Frank Sorry for that. Not perfect representative sample of my data. Indeed Thats the reason why Jaap is not able to see the correct problem.

Comment: @Jaap  Sorry for the confusion as Frank pointed out. Ideally I wanted this operation inside each and every column. I am having huge datatable. Creating factor out of all such string values could be pain and I also need to retrieve the original value post my model building in Spark. (PS: I did wrote a big clarifying comment to explain you better about this problem but somehow it got lost while I trying to post update to the question as well, per Frank suggestion) Though solution doesn't match expected one but nonetheless I will start thinking considering your solution.

Comment: @Jaap sure liked Frank's parsimonious code. Couldn't see his comment mentioning this though.

Comment: @abhiieor Sorry for the confusion; sent it to Jaap elsewhere :) Alternate version with the magrittr package: `lapply(.SD, . %>% as.factor %>% as.integer)`